How to add a when condition while creating chatparticipant in vscode extension?
As we have a when condition in commands, do we have a similar condition in chatparticipant too?
Tried added but didn't work as expected.
Basically, I used a flag to set and unset it, but it is not working as expected. I am not sure if this when conditions even exists for chatparticipant

have you considered raising a feature-request issue ticket? if you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
